# CfEngine - Call variables and classes from different CF or promises.cf

Tags: linux, cfengine

I want to put `body package_method` and some variables in promises.cf or in a different file and I should be able to call it from any new CF files I write.

Is that possible? I could not find anything related to such methods in the documentation.

I was thinking of creating a new file in `/var/cfengine/masterfiles/` and then edit `/var/cfengine/promises.cf` and insert the new file as `inputs` but it did not work out.

Here is what I want to put (in a new file maybe) which should be accessible globally.

```
bundle common variables
{
   vars:
          "global_var_1" string  => "value_var_1";
}
```

and

```
body package_method yum
{
   any::
   package_changes => "bulk";
   package_list_command => "/usr/bin/yum list installed";
   package_list_name_regex => "([^.]+).*";
   package_list_version_regex => "[^\s]\s+([^\s]+).*";
   package_list_arch_regex => "[^.]+\.([^\s]+).*";
   package_installed_regex => ".*installed.*";
   package_name_convention => "$(name).$(arch)";

   package_name_regex => "amanda-client";
   package_arch_regex => "x86_64";
   package_add_command => "/usr/bin/yum -y install";
   package_delete_command => "/bin/rpm -e";
   package_verify_command => "/bin/rpm -V";
}
```

Then I should be able call it in any new CF as:

```
"${variables.global_var_1}"
```

and

```
bundle agent packages
{
   packages:
           "wget"
                   package_policy => "add",
                   package_method => yum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

## To create Global Variables:

Create a `variables.cf` and in that file insert the following lines.

```
bundle common variables
{
   vars:
          "global_var_1" string  => "value_var_1";
 }
```

Then create any CF but under the `body common control` - input the `variables.cf` file.

```
body common control
{
bundlesequence => { "myclasses" };
inputs => { "variables.cf" };
}
```

Then you can call the variables as `"${variables.global_var_1}"`.

## To call `package_method` globally:

Under any new CF `body common control` input the file `/var/cfengine/masterfiles/lib/packages.cf`

```
body common control
{
bundlesequence => { "myclasses", "packages_to_install" };
inputs => { "/var/cfengine/masterfiles/lib/packages.cf" };
}
```

Then you can add packages like

```
bundle agent packages_to_install
{
packages:
          "wget"
                 package_policy => "add",
                  package_method => yum;
}
```